# Azure ML Client Authentication Failure

Tags: azure-managed-identity, azureml-python-sdk

**I am trying to authenticate the Azure ML Client through the following code running on Spark cluster:**

```
os.environ["AZURE_ML_CLI_PRIVATE_FEATURES_ENABLED"] = "true"
os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"] = subscription_id
os.environ["AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP"] = resource_group
os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"] = client_id
os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"] = tenant_id
os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"] = client_secret

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=client_id)
credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default", tenant_id = tenant_id )
ml_client = MLClient(credential, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
```

**The first time, it asks me to log in through the browser.**

> Resolving access token for scope "https://storage.azure.com/.default" using identity of type "USER".
> InteractiveBrowserCredential.get_token failed: Failed to open a browser
> To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code

**Then, the second time I run the code, it goes through the authentication without asking to log in from the browser again.**

**How do you ensure the browser login is not popping up, and it can authenticate transparently?**

Thanks